# Cordova platform ios selecting an image from gallery issue

Tags: ios, cordova

I'm using cordova to run my app on ios platform. When I select image from device gallery I'm attaching this image to background of current view and that's working fine. I need somehow to save this image to the local storage and when I reload app to get that image on my background. I tried this with saving URL of image which I'm using on first attempt but It's seems that this image changing id in URL each time when I reload an app. How can I do it is there any another way or something similar?

Comment: Could you please paste some code, how you are getting it from gallary

Comment: pictureSource = navigator.camera.PictureSourceType
getPhoto(pictureSource.PHOTOLIBRARY)

Comment: and than I got imageURI... which I'm using to make in css backround-image: URL(imageURI)... I save this URI to local storage but after app reload I cannot see image...

Comment: Instead of saving image uri you should save the image data and load the image content some thing like this bannerImage = document.getElementById('bannerImg');
imgData = getBase64Image(bannerImage);
localStorage.setItem("imgData", imgData);

Comment: and get the image form local storage and display it again

Comment: ok thanks I will try now back here in few minutes...

Comment: It's working thanks I just converter my imageURI to base64 and that's it thanks!

Comment: No problem, I will paste this in the answer section.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Instead of saving image uri you should save the image data and load the image content some thing like this

```
bannerImage = document.getElementById('bannerImg'); imgData = getBase64Image(bannerImage); localStorage.setItem("imgData", imgData);
```

and get the image form local storage and display it again.